# 25 pebbles are placed in a 5 by 5 grid. How many ways can the pebbles be picked so that no two of them are in the same row or column?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have the following problem for a math competition I am studying for:

25 pebbles are placed in a 5 by 5 grid. How many ways can 5 pebbles
be picked so that no two of them are in the same row or column?

The answer key says that the answer is 120 however, I don't know how it got it. I am guessing this has something to do with permutations and/or combinations.

Comment: What do you mean by *"In how many ways can the pebbles be picked..."*? How many pebbles are you picking?

Comment: It doesn't specify how many pebbles are being picked, however, I think it means how many different ways can you pick the pebbles.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. That depends on the number of pebbles you are picking. You can pick one pebble in $25$ ways. But you cannot pick six pebbles in such a way that no two of them are in the same row or column.

Comment: Ok I talked to one of the people and he said it was for 5 pebbles being removed

Answer (score 1):

They intend you to choose five pebbles.  You have five choices for the pebble in the first row, then four for the one in the second row, and so on to just one in the fifth row.  That gives $5!=120$ possibilities.